# Outlook 2011 Standard server settings keep changing

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook

This issue did not occur until we upgraded to Exchange Server 2010.

So, this is what happens:

1. select ADD ACCOUNT in Outlook 2011
2. enter the correct user info then un-check "Auto Configure Server"
3. enter our OWA address "https://mail.ourcompany.com"

The next day, the user will check their server setting and see that it's been changed to `server name.company.local`

I have no idea why this happens but I'm guessing it's related to Exchange 2010 since this did not occur with Exchange 2007.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: So the client is a Mac?

Comment: So what problem is this causing you? I'm not really familiar with Outlook 2011, but it *sounds* like normal behaviour of pointing you to a CAS (Server|Array). If anything, I imagine it'll be AutoDiscover settings.

Comment: Well, I guess it's not fair to call it an issue, but what that does is make it so users cannot sync email via Outlook "without" having to use the VPN. When it points back to the local server, they have to log onto the VPN (which they should anyway) but... I was asked to ask.

Comment: And yes, the clients are Macs.

Comment: @ben-pilbrow is correct it is normal operation.  Based on your comments, my guess is that you want these macs to access outlook over EWS (Exchange web services) but it is possible that the EWS settings are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In outlook 2011, the place where you type your server name, make sure you put this at the end:   EWS/Exchange.asmx
so if your domain is mail.ourcompany.com, you would type the whole domain as follows:   `https://mail.ourcompany.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`

also for directory service, put in your active directory ip or name.

This is ONLY an issue with Mac outlook 2011 connecting to Exchange 2010

Do you have the proper port forwarding in place for your exchange server?  That will cause difficulty with connecting to exchange from the outside for sure...

Has your admin configured the autodiscover service?  This may help you tremendously to get connected through EWS.

Pass [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201695.aspx) Technet article along to them.

Comment: I tried adding that but no go. It still changes back to the host name.